# isDigit() keeps returning 0 even if it's a digit, C language

Tags: c

```
//Checks if it's an integer, other wise halt the program
    void checkInt(char s[]){
        int i;
        boolean boo = TRUE;
        fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i){
            printf("%d",isdigit(s[i]));
            if (!(isdigit(s[i]))){
                boo = FALSE;
                printf("Invalid input!\n");
                printf("CLOSING PROGRAM");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("Cool");
        }  
    }


    int main()
    {
        int userInput;
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        char buf[sizeof(int)*3+2];
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", userInput);
        checkInt(buf);
        return 0;
    }
```

I been playing around with this for a while now, I just don't seem to get why my isDigit always return 0 when I'm passing a digit in it? I Tried using the online Iodeone.com and it works as expected, but when I use compile what my teacher wants us to use, is digit all of the sudden don't recognize they are digits

Comment: You should post some code that actually shows the problem, not something that depends on user input.

Comment: @juanchopanza the problem depends on the userInput, because I'm trying to make a checkInt function that checks if it's an Integer, if not, program halts.

Comment: So why don't you ask about inputting numbers? Problem solving skills: isolate the problem as much as possible.

Comment: Your function should check whether a string is an integer, nothing else. Don't miox it with user input, which should come from outside the function. (As indeed it does: You pass an integer converted to a string to the function.)

Comment: @MOehm I needed the userInput to be integer for future use. Regardless, I figured it out how to make it work, thanks though.

Comment: @xpluffy: That doesn't mean that you have to overwrite the argument that you pass into the function with user input. Exiting from this function on error also looks like poor style to me. in my opinion, your function should just check the string and maybe convert it. The client code then should decide what to do based on the function's result. Well, never mind.

Answer (score 2):

Several things wrong with your code:

1. you initialize a buffer to pass to `checkInt()`, but inside `checkInt()` you ignore what's in that buffer by overwriting it with a call to `fgets()`;
2. the variable `s` in `checkInt()` is really a pointer, not an array, so `sizeof(s)` isn't giving you the size that you want;
3. the `fgets()` that overwrites the data passed into `checkInt()` likely just reads a newline left in the `stdin` stream by the `scanf()` call - so the buffer basically gets set to a string that's equivalent to `"\n"`.  That's why the `isdigit()` call never sees a digit.

Comment: And what is the thinking behind the size calculation for the size of the `buf` array: `sizeof(int)*3+2`?